# How to expose classes from other Typescript declaration files

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I'm building a node module in Javascript, that exposes 3 classes:

```js
//index.js
module.exports = {
  ClassA,
  ClassB,
  ClassC,
}
```

I would like to write a Typescript declaration file, that pulls these classes from other declaration files for organizational purposes. Something like this, for example:

```
//index.d.ts

import { ClassA } from './classA.d.ts';
import { ClassB } from './classB.d.ts';
import { ClassC } from './classC.d.ts';

declare module 'myModule' {
  export ClassA;
  export ClassB;
  export ClassC;
}
```

```
//classA.d.ts

export class ClassA {
  foo:string;
  bar:number;
}
```

I'm having a hard time getting this to work, and I've tried a variety of permutations; anytime I use import in `index.d.ts` something from another local files, I get several errors. Inserting the entire set of class definitions in `index.d.ts` works fine, but I'm hoping to organize them into separate files.

Using Typescript 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

**index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="./classA.d.ts" />

declare module 'myModule' {
   import { ClassA as MyClassA } from 'myModule/classA';

   class ClassA extends MyClassA {}
}
```

**classA.d.ts**

```
declare module 'myModule/classA' {
  export class ClassA {
    foo:string;
    bar:number;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got a small tip for you in case of importing things in a declaration file which I usually do:

`index.d.ts`

```js
declare module 'myModule' {
  // it returns a promise so have to resolve it
  const moduleA = await import('./classA.d.ts');

  export class ClassA extends moduleA.ClassA {}

  // Likewise for others
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tmhao2005, this is interesting. Would you mind sharing what your `classA.d.ts` file would look like to make this work?

Comment: It's just a normal class like yours. Did you make it working?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The Typescript compiler doesn't seem to care for the `await import` in my type definition file.